# Nested queries in MYSQL and nodejs Async Issue

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

I want to execute an sql query for every row of another query so i wrote a function like

```
export function getLocations(req, res) {
let appData = [];
const database = new Database();
database.query('select * from districts')
    .then(rows => {
        rows.forEach(row => {
            const new_database = new Database();
            new_database.query(`SELECT locations.id,locations.name
            FROM locations 
            .....
            WHERE locations.district=?`, row.id)
                .then(sub_rows => {
                    let district = row;
                    district["locations"] = sub_rows;
                    appData.push(district);
                    new_database.close();
                }, err => {
                    return new_database.close().then(() => { throw err; })
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(500).json("Database Error");
                })
    }, err => {
        return database.close().then(() => { throw err; })
    }).then(result => {
        //final result
        res.status(200).json(appData);
        database.close()
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json("Database Error");
    })
}
```

and my database class is

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

class Database {
constructor() {
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        port: 3306,
        debug: false,
        multipleStatements: false
    });
}
query(sql, args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.connection.query(sql, args, (err, rows) => {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);
            resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}
close() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.connection.end(err => {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
}
module.exports = Database;
```

This however on execution goes on and print the final result (empty array) without waiting to execute the sub queries. I tried async await on **row** and **new_database.query** but still it doesn't wait for subquery execution to finish. What can I do here?

Comment: since `appData` is built using the asynchronous result of `new_database.query`, and there's no promise returned from within that `.then` ... the next `.then` will be called too early - you'll need to use `promises` correctly - perhaps `return new_database.query(.... etc` will be enough

Comment: i tried return and still the result is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have improved your logic for `sub-queries` and re-wrote them using [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
export function getLocations(req, res) {
    let appData = [];
    const database = new Database();
    database.query('select * from districts')
        .then(rows => {

            // create promise list for all sub-queries
            const promise_list = rows.map(row => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const new_database = new Database();
                return new_database.query(`SELECT locations.id,locations.name FROM locations .... WHERE locations.district=?`, row.id)
                    .then(sub_rows => {
                        let district = row;
                        district["locations"] = sub_rows;
                        appData.push(district);
                        new_database.close();
                        resolve(district);
                    }, err => {
                        return new_database.close().then(() => { throw err; })
                    });
            })
            );

            // execute all sub-queries in parallel and wait for them
            Promise.all(promise_list).then(result => {
                res.status(200).json(appData);
                database.close()
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).json("Database Error");
            });

        });
}
```

PS: You can declare `appData` as `const`, you're just pushing data into it. Not re-assigning it.

Comment: i logged and now the execution is in correct order but is not returning and stuck. the final result is not printed and is always waiting.

Comment: @AnoopKrishnan remove `return` from line `return new_database.close();` and add`resolve(district)` after that. I am also editing the answer to make it more clear. Unfortunately I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN to try to get the result you are after. What functions are available depends on MySQL version so you might need [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) instead of [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)

```
SELECT districts.*, JSON_ARRAYAGG(locations)
FROM districts
LEFT JOIN locations
   ON locations.district=districts.id
GROUP BY districts.id
```

Javascript joins have horrible performance so let the database do what its designed to do.

Comment: i had redacted my actual query in the post. they are not "joinable"